# How to read a 10 GB txt file consisting of tab-separated double data line by line in C

Tags: c, arrays, io, fgets

I have a txt file consisting of tab-separated data with type `double`. The data file is over 10 GB, so I just wish to read the data line-by-line and then do some processing. Particularly, the data is layout as an matrix with, say 1001 columns, and millions of rows. Below is just a fake sample to show the layout.

```
10.2  30.4  42.9 ... 3232.000 23232.45
...
...
7.234  824.23232 ... 4009.23  230.01
...
```

For each line I'd like to store the first 1000 values in an array, and the last value in a separate variable. I am new to C, so it would be nice if you could kindly point out major steps.

**Update:**

Thanks for all valuable suggestions and solutions. I just figured out one simple example where I just read a 3-by-4 matrix row by row from a txt file. For each row, the first 3 elements are stored in `x`, and the last element is stored in vector `y`. So `x` is a `n-by-p` matrix with `n=p=3`, `y` is a `1-by-3` vector.

Below is my data file and my code.

Data file:

```
1.112272    -0.345324   0.608056    0.641006
-0.358203   0.300349    -1.113812   -0.321359
0.155588    2.081781    0.038588    -0.562489
```

My code:

```
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define n 3
#define p 3

void main() {

    FILE *fpt;
    fpt = fopen("./data_temp.txt", "r");    

    char line[n*(p+1)*sizeof(double)];
    char *token;
    double *x;
    x = malloc(n*p*sizeof(double));
    double y[n];

    int index = 0;
    int xind = 0;
    int yind = 0;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fpt)) {
        //printf("%d\n", sizeof(line));
        //printf("%s\n", line);

        token = strtok(line, "\t");
        while(token != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", token);

            if((index+1) % (p+1) == 0) { // the last element in each line;
                yind = (index + 1) / (p+1) - 1; // get index for y vector;
                sscanf(token, "%lf", &(y[yind]));
            } else {
                sscanf(token, "%lf", &(x[xind]));
                xind++;
            }
            //sscanf(token, "%lf", &(x[index]));
            index++;
            token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
        } 
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    puts("Print x matrix:");
    for(i = 0; i < n*p; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", x[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    puts("Print y vector:");
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%f\t", y[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(x);
    fclose(fpt);
}
```

With above, hopefully things will work if I replace `data_temp.txt` with my raw 10 GB data file (of course change values of `n`,`p`, and some other code wherever necessary.)

I have additional questions that I wish if you could help me.

1. I first initialized `char line[]` as `char line[(p+1)*sizeof(double)]` (note not multiplying `n`). But the line cannot be read completely. How could I assign memory JUST for one single line? What's the lenght? I assume it's `(p+1)*sizeof(double)` since there are `(p+1)` doubles in each line. Should I also assign memory for `\t` and `\n`? If so, how?
2. Does the code look reasonable to you? How could I make it more efficient since this code will be executed over millions of rows?
3. If I don't know the number of columns or rows in the raw 10 GB file, how could I quickly count rows and columns?

Again I am new to `C`, any comments are very appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should break this down into several questions, asked one after the other. And you should try something first and pass some code along with your first question. Do you really want to use C or are you going for C++ ? And my personal opinion is that you either need a lot of memory or should try something else than storing all the values ...

Comment: Use fgets to read the file line by line, then use strtok to split each line in separate string values, and finally sscanf to convert the string values to double. Write some code, and either add it here if it is still coherent with current question, or ask a new question if it is a different (hopefully more precise) problem.

Comment: Do you need to store all the lines at once or can you process one at a time? If you need to operate on them all at once then you'll need a *lot* of ram (or a lot of time if it uses swap space).

Comment: @Marged, I will play around with others' suggestions and update my question. Is there a particular reason to go for C++ given this huge data? I am pretty new to both C and C++, so not sure why I should use C++.

Comment: C is a great programming language but C++ offers you more high level functions and C++ being object oriented might make it easier for you to code a solution. It does not solve your memory problem

Comment: And this is something that C# could do pretty easily as well right out of the box (or name your string loving language).  Lots of choices.

Comment: @SergeBallesta. Thanks for the instruction. I followed that I figured out one simple solution.

Comment: @or1426, no. I just need to read line-by-line (or chunk-by-chunk), and do some calculations, then can remove those from memory and go to next.

Comment: @Marged, I see. Since I have no knowledge of C++ at all, so not sure whether I need to learn it. In your opinion, would there be a good amount of benefit using C++ in my case? If so, I will try C++ instead.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, The bigger story is that I need to build an R package with low level C code to handle the messy computation. I don't see C# work. Thanks for pointing out that though.

Comment: Shouldn't this work with R directly ? I see no point in using C to read such simple data and forward this to R.

Comment: @Marged, the thing is that, first the data is really huge; and second, I need to implement an algorithm which involves tons of this kind of computation on this huge file. My question just illustrates my VERY FIRST step. R cannot handle huge file larger than memory, nor can do fast computing.

Answer (score 1):

*1st way*

Read file in chunks into preallocated buffer using `fread`.

*2nd way*

Map the file into your process memory space using `mmap`, move the pointer then over the file.

Answer (score 0):

*3rd way*

Since your file is delimited by lines, open the file with `fopen`, use `setvbuf` or similar to set a buffer size greater than about 10 lines or so, then read the file line-by-line using `fgets`.

To potentially read the file even faster, use `open` with `O_DIRECT` (assuming Linux), then use `fdopen` to get a `FILE *` for the open file, then use `setvbuf` to set a page-aligned buffer.  Doing that will allow you to bypass the kernel page cache - if your system's implementation works successfully using direct IO that way.  (There can be many restrictions to direct IO)

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you started: Reading 1 line

```
#define COLUMN (1000+1)
double data[COLUMNS];

for (int i = 0; i< COLUMN; i++) {
  char delim = '\n';
  int cnt = fscanf(in_stream, "%lf%c", &data[i], &delim);
  if (cnt < 1) {
    if (cnt == EOF && i == 0) return 0; // None read, OK as end of file
    puts("Missing or bad data");
    return -1; // problem
  }
  if (delim  != '\t') {
    // If tab not found, should be at end of line
    if (delim  == '\n' && i == COLUMN-1) {
      return COLUMN;  // Success
    } 
    puts("Bad delimiter");
    return -1;
  }
}
puts("Extra data");
return -1;
```